# Reformat Javascript date object

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date object that I want to reformat to a different date style, but am having trouble doing so. I've tried `.format()` and using `moment`, but can't get it to work (`.format()` just throws a `start.format("YYYY/DDD") is not a function` error and `moment` seems to only return Unix timestamps no matter what I do.  I keep getting `Invalid Date`.  Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t92dvhL/) with my code in it (the dates are displayed when you hover over a block of time).

As requested, here is the actual code:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'RowLabel' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'BlockLabel' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
  ["SAT 2B", "Task 1", new Date(2015, 01, 01), new Date(2015, 02, 02)],
  ["SAT 2B", "Task 2", new Date(2015, 01, 05), new Date(2015, 01, 08)],
  ["SAT 2B", "Task 1", new Date("2015-03-10 05:10:39.010000"), new Date("2015-03-15 05:10:39.010000")],
  ["SAT 2C", "Task 1", new Date("2015-04-10 05:10:39.010000"), new Date("2015-04-15 05:10:39.010000")]
  ]);


  var options = {
    timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true }
  };


  chart.draw(dataTable, options);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(e) {
    setTooltipContent(dataTable,e.row);
  });
}


function setTooltipContent(dataTable,row) {

  if (row != null) {
    var sat = dataTable.getValue(row,0);
    var taskID = dataTable.getValue(row,1);
    //var start = dataTable.getValue(row,2);
    var start = dataTable.getValue(row,2).toDateString();
    var startFormatted = new Date(start, "dd.mm.yyyy hh:MM:ss")
    //start.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    //start.format('yyyy/DDD-HH:mm:ss');
    var end = dataTable.getValue(row,3);

    var content = '<div class="custom-tooltip" ><h1>' + sat + ','+ taskID +'</h1><div>' +'Start:'+startFormatted +', End: '+ end+'</div></div>'; //generate tooltip content
    var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("google-visualization-tooltip")[0];
    tooltip.innerHTML = content;
  }
}
```

To the best of my knowledge what I am trying to reformat is a date object so I'm not sure what is going wrong.  I want it to display in the `YYYY/DDD HH:mm:ss` format (where `DDD` is day of year).

Comment: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is your savior.

Comment: Put your code *in the question*, not in a link to JSFiddle.

Comment: @JeremyThille I tried using moment like this: `var start = moment(dataTable.getValue(row,2),"YYYY/DDD_HH:mm:ss");` but that didn't work.

Comment: In this particular instance, it looks like one problem, probably the first you need to fix, is that you're using the Date constructor incorrectly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date .. if you want to get it into a date object, you'll want to omit the second argument as that's only used when doing Date(year, month[,etc]). This will solve your Invalid Date issue, then you can deal with getting your date into the format you want.

Comment: @Mic I tried changing it to `var startFormatted = new Date(start)` and `startFormatted.format("YYYY/DDD")` and that produced the `.format() is not a function` error

Comment: Yes, because it's not a function (See my MDN link again)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r35066q4/1/ Check this out - forked from yours. Manually formatted. Probably want to pad leading zeroes in front of the time fields to make sure they're two digits.

Comment: @Mic that looks good except it doesn't seem to be picking up the times (it shows `0:0:0` for all of them but the last two blocks have time)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to use the date like this:

```
var start = dataTable.getValue(row,2).toDateString();
var startFormatted = moment(start).format("YYYY/DDD HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score -1):

have you looked into http://momentjs.com/ or http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format 
Makes dealing with js dates so much easier